# Hirsute hippo: Can't find Russian "phonetic keyboard" (ЯВЕРТЫ)

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support

I believe Ubuntu 21.04 is "stable" as of today, but it has no Russian phonetic keyboard. All I can find in Hippo is the quaintly denominated "Russian (polyglot and reactionary)", which as far as I can see is identical to the standard Russian.

I hope the Russian phonetic keyboard is just around the corner. It has been on every long-term version of Ubuntu for at least 15 years. It is very useful for non-Russians and for people who type mostly on qwerty boards and only occasionally switch to Russian.

Comment: Beta is off topic

Comment: Please file a proper [bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). The best time to file that bug report was last week, unfortunately.

Comment: FYI on Ubuntu MATE it is named as English (US), Russian (US, phonetic). The screenshot [is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R3iN.png). Does it suite your needs?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 is shipped with the same version of the `xkb-data` package as in 20.04 and 20.10, so nothing has changed. And multiple variants are available, including the one named _Russian (phonetic)_. Possibly you are struggling with the GNOME settings GUI. If you have generated a Russian locale, the Russian keyboard layouts are shown in a sub menu which opens if you select _Russian_.

Comment: @gunnar Please tell me what commands to enter. I have:
~$ setxkbmap -query  
rules: evdev  
model:pc105  layout:us    
  
~$ locale -a  
...  
is_IS.utf8  
nb_NO.utf8  
POSIX  
ru_RU.utf8  
ru_UA.utf8   

~$ locale  
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8  
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en  
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"  
LC_NUMERIC=nb_NO.UTF-8   
etc.

Comment: As advised I have now filed a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1925792

Comment: Not sure this is a bug. Please try: `sudo apt install --reinstall xkb-data` and relogin. Do you see more Russian layout options now?

Comment: I ran  "sudo apt install --reinstall xkb-data" and "sudo apt update" and rebooted. No change. The "locale -a" was also unchanged.

Comment: Now I see the problem. I think the _Russian (phonetic)_ layout can be found if you don't click "Russian" but instead proceed to the window with "Other" input sources.

Comment: This is terribly embarrassing, but I cannot find any window with "other" input sources.

Comment: @user297116: Click the + button. At the bottom there are three dots in a vertical row (More...). Click that to reach the second window. At the bottom of the second window there is an "Other" option.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed bug.
Cf. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1925792
Thank you Gunnar Hjalmarsson.
Meanwhile, to summarise discussion, a workaround: Language settings > input sources > "+" > three tiny vertical dots > scroll to bottom > "other". You will find a long list of alternative keyboards, including Russian phonetic.